# Are questions about Anki Overdrive on topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm wondering if questions about [Anki Overdrive](https://anki.com/en-us/overdrive) are on topic here.

Arguments I can think of are:

**Pros**

- You need mobile computers to play it
- Questions will be either about the cars and tracks (fits `Game-specific hardware and utilities`), `Gameplay strategies and tactics` or about the software running on the mobile phone
- It is for sure off topic on [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/)

**Cons**

- It is basically only a "better" slot car racing game with fancy controllers
- It is not playable without the actual cars and tracks

IMO it is on topic, but I'd like to hear other opinions before I ask.

Comment: At first glance, I'd say *probably* on-topic. At least - as far as the app is concerned. Gets a bit more iffy the more you move into the physical side of it (the cars themselves and the track). But that *should* be covered, as you pointed out, by "Game-specific hardware".

Comment: It's effectively a slot-car racer with a video game overlay as the controller. The first would be off-topic without the second - but since the first and the second cannot operate independently, they should be considered part of a single unit and the whole thing on-topic (or, at least, that's my thinking.)

Comment: Why are you saying it is "for sure off-topic" on board and card games? They don't seem to have a meta on this, and I'm not quite sure if this is off-topic by looking at their help page.

Comment: @Wipqozn the [summary on Board & Card games](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) contains `Be playable on or around a table` and `Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules`. While Overdrive could be played on a (very large) table the human players are not implementing the rules, the computer does. I think the best match of the Overdrive concept is that it is similar to Rockband or Guitar Hero, which also have specialized hardware that is only usable along with the computer game.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say **yes**, this kind of game would be on topic enough to try it out.

As others have pointed out in the comments, I think this game follows our guidelines enough to give it a run and see what traction it gets from the community (there aren't that many products like this out there so it shouldn't lead to a flood of questions or anything).

My only real concern is whether it would get more useful answers here or on Boardgames SE (though that's just speculation on my part).

As to it being on topic on Boardgames SE, I feel like that's open to discussion and would be a good question for their meta site (a lot of ["traditional games" have been blurring the lines](http://www.avclub.com/article/two-recent-board-games-show-potential-app-and-tabl-216043) as of late).